# Blank Maze Generation

Tags: actionscript-3, maze

Maze is generating in a weird fashion. I do not know why, but it generates and breaks down every wall.
here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{   
    //ARRAYS
    private var maze:Array = new Array();
    private var pos:Array = new Array();

    //INTEGERS
    private var num:int = 50;

    private var cellX:int = 0;
    private var cellY:int = 0;
    private var mazeX:int = num;
    private var mazeY:int = num;


    //POINTS
    private var startCell:Point = new Point();

    //SPRITES
    private var mazeSpriteT:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var mazeSpriteB:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var mazeSpriteL:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var mazeSpriteR:Sprite = new Sprite();

    //broken wall
    private var brWall:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Main():void
    {   

        //creating the initial grid, cells and points
        setMaze();
        //calling function to generate maze
        generate(startCell);

    }

    public function setMaze():void
    {

        //clearing the screen from all graphical images
        mazeSpriteT.graphics.clear();
        mazeSpriteB.graphics.clear();
        mazeSpriteR.graphics.clear();
        mazeSpriteL.graphics.clear();
        brWall.graphics.clear();

        maze = new Array();
        pos = new Array();

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            maze[i] = new Array();
            pos[i] = new Array();

            for (var j:int = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                //maze
                maze[i][j] = new Cell;
                maze[i][j].visited = false;

                //pos
                pos[i][j] = new Point(cellX, cellY);


                //graphics
                mazeSpriteT.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1); 
                mazeSpriteB.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1); 
                mazeSpriteR.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1); 
                mazeSpriteL.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x000000, 1); 

                //toplines
                addChild(mazeSpriteT);
                mazeSpriteT.graphics.moveTo(mazeX, mazeY);
                mazeSpriteT.graphics.lineTo(mazeX + num, mazeY);
                mazeSpriteT = new Sprite();

                //bottomlines
                addChild(mazeSpriteB);
                mazeSpriteB.graphics.moveTo(mazeX, mazeY + num);
                mazeSpriteB.graphics.lineTo(mazeX + num, mazeY + num);
                mazeSpriteB = new Sprite();

                //rightlines
                addChild(mazeSpriteR);
                mazeSpriteR.graphics.moveTo(mazeX + num, mazeY);
                mazeSpriteR.graphics.lineTo(mazeX + num, mazeY + num);
                mazeSpriteR = new Sprite();

                //leftlines
                addChild(mazeSpriteL);
                mazeSpriteL.graphics.moveTo(mazeX, mazeY);
                mazeSpriteL.graphics.lineTo(mazeX, mazeY + num);
                mazeSpriteB = new Sprite();


                cellX += 10;
                mazeX += num;

            }

            cellX = 0;
            cellY += 10;

            mazeX = num;
            mazeY += num;

        }

        //maze entrance
        startCell = pos[0][0];

    }

    public function generate(cell:Point):void 
    {
        var cx:int = cell.x / 10;
        var cy:int = cell.y / 10;

        maze[cy][cx].visited = true;
        var neighbours:Array = new Array();
        fillNeighbours(neighbours, cell);

        trace(neighbours.length);

        while (neighbours.length > 0) {

            var index:int = (Math.random() * neighbours.length);
            Math.floor(index);
            var arr:Array = neighbours.splice(index, 1);
            var pnt:Point = new Point(arr[0].x, arr[0].y);
            breakWall(cell, pnt);
            generate(pnt);

            //trace("index: " + index);
            //trace("obx: " + arr[0].x + " oby: " + arr[0].y);
            //trace("pnt: " + pnt);


        }

    }

    public function fillNeighbours(neighbours:Array, cell:Point):Array
    {
        var cx:int = cell.x / 10;
        var cy:int = cell.y / 10;

        /*for (var i:int = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {

            for (var j:int = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {

                //outerwall parameters
                maze[0][j].north = false;
                maze[maze.length - 1][j].south = false;
                maze[i][maze[i].length-1].east = false;
                maze[i][0].west = false;

            }

        }   */


        //south neigbours
        if (cy < maze.length - 1) {

            if (maze[cy + 1][cx].visited == true) {

                maze[cy][cx].south = false;

            } else {

                neighbours.push(pos[cy + 1][cx]);

            }

        }

        if (cy > 0) {

            //north neighbours
            if (maze[cy - 1][cx].visited == true) {

                maze[cy][cx].north = false;

            } else {

                neighbours.push(pos[cy - 1][cx]);

            }

        }

        if (cx < maze.length - 1) {

            //east neighbours
            if (maze[cy][cx + 1].visited == true) {

                maze[cy][cx].east = false;

            } else {

                neighbours.push(pos[cy][cx + 1]);

            }

        }

        if (cx > 0) {

            //west neighbours
            if (maze[cy][cx - 1].visited == true) {

                maze[cy][cx].west = false;

            } else {

                neighbours.push(pos[cy][cx - 1]);

            }

        }

        trace("--");
        return(neighbours);

    }

    public function breakWall(cell:Point, pnt:Point):void
    {

        var cx:int = cell.x / 10;
        var cy:int = cell.y / 10;
        var px:int = pnt.x / 10;
        var py:int = pnt.y / 10;

        brWall.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFFFFFF, 1); //white walls

        addChild(brWall);

        trace(cx, px);

        if (cy == py) { //horizontal transition

            if (cx > px) { //right to left

                brWall.graphics.moveTo((cx * num) + num, (cy * num) + num);
                brWall.graphics.lineTo((cx * num) + num, (cy * num) + (num * 2));

            } else if (cx < px) { //left to right

                brWall.graphics.moveTo((cx * num) + (num * 2), (cy * num) + (num * 2));
                brWall.graphics.lineTo((cx * num) + (num * 2), (cy * num) + num);

            }

        }

        if (cx == px) { //vertical transition

            if (cy > py) { //down to up

                brWall.graphics.moveTo((cx * num) + (num * 2), (cy * num) + num);
                brWall.graphics.lineTo((cx * num) + num, (cy * num) + num);

            } else if (cy < py){ //up to down

                brWall.graphics.moveTo((cx * num) + num, (cy * num) + (num * 2));
                brWall.graphics.lineTo((cx * num) + (num * 2), (cy * num) + (num * 2));

            }

        }

        brWall = new Sprite();

    }

}
```

}

I have been praying for help. Be the one to answer my prayers (I will give you five internet dollars).

Comment: By breaking down every wall, I mean to say that every part of the grid other than the border is blank, as if the maze goes everywhere in every direction. sorry for the lack of clarification, if you need more explanation on anything let me know

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand completely. You're running a loop that breaks down each wall

```
while (neighbours.length > 0) {

            var index:int = (Math.random() * neighbours.length);
            Math.floor(index);
            var arr:Array = neighbours.splice(index, 1);
            var pnt:Point = new Point(arr[0].x, arr[0].y);
            breakWall(cell, pnt);
            generate(pnt);

            //trace("index: " + index);
            //trace("obx: " + arr[0].x + " oby: " + arr[0].y);
            //trace("pnt: " + pnt);
    }
```

Just remove `breakWall(cell,pnt)`?

Comment: I need this function to break down the walls and visually create the maze. But I am interested in how you think removing the call would work. Would you mind explaining?